# Casting Azure Blob Item to Java File Object

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

So the existing code base where I work uses a regular Java File("a/directory/path") object for a massive amount of logic. Now my team wants me to use a file stored in the Azure Blob instead. I can get the file from the blob using the CloudBlobItem() java api. But this object is different than a regular java File() object. And I would have to change a bunch of stuff in the logic. Is there any blob item which can be casted to a regular File() object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

You're comparing two completely different things. Azure blobs are not files. You'd need to stream them down to where your code is running. Maybe to a file stream. Maybe write to disk. And then work with the file. You cannot just use an Azure blob like any other file I/O.

Note: If you're using Azure File Storage (which is an SMB share), then you *do* treat everything in that file store like you'd treat local storage. But it sounds like you're just using normal block blobs for your storage.